# Nested functions are disabled

Tags: c

I've got two distinct compilation errors in this piece of code, both located in the main.

main.c:50: error: nested functions are disabled, use -fnested-functions to re-enable
main.c:72: error: expected declaration or statement at end of input

What am I missing?

Thanks a lot !

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int     ft_putline(int h, int l, int type)
{
    int     i;
    int     x;

    i = 0;

    x = 0; 

while(type == 1) /* Cette boucle affiche la première et la dernière ligne.*/
{
     if(i == 0)
    {
        printf("o");
        i++;
     }

    else if(i != 0 && i < l)
    {
        printf("-");
        i++;
    }
    else if(i == l)
     { 
        printf("o");
        printf("\n");
        type = type - 1;

     }

while(type == 0 && x >= h - (h - 1) && x <= h - 1) 

 {
    i = 0;

    x = 0;

    if(i = 0) 
    {
        printf("|");
        i++;
    }   
 }      

}

int     main()
{

int     l;
int     type; 
int     h;

l = 0;

type = 1;

h = 0;

printf("quelle est la largeur du rectangle ?\n");

scanf("%d", &h);

printf("quelle est la hauteur du rectangle ?\n");

scanf("%d", &l);


return (0);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon. It would help to include the exact error messages and the line numbers — and identify those lines in the code you include.

Comment: You are missing a closing bracket.  That would much easier to see if you keep your code consistently indented.

Comment: "What am I missing?" Specific error messages, line numbers where the errors are happening, and proper code indentation, to start.

Comment: Sorry Everyone, I'll edit my post straight away. @ shf301 where? my main has an opening and a closing bracket...

Comment: HipVegas, I think that's exactly the point that @shf301 was trying to make. :)  Your `main` begins inside of `ft_putline`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need another brace `}`.

You could put it

1) just before the `main` function.

or

2) just before `while(type == 0`.

Two lessons here:

- The problem would have been obvious to you had you indented your code
  properly.
- Without any program comments I can't decipher your intention.

Either way will get your code to compile, but the runtime effects are very different.

Comment: Thanks for this very easily readable answer ; ) And sorry for my evident noobness everyone...

Answer (score 2):

Your first `while` loop in `ft_putline()` is not terminated properly, so `main()` appears to be inside `ft_putline()`.